# Connection refused due to limit in the number of request connection attempts

Tags: python, azure, request, azure-iot-hub

I have a script running on the edge in Azure IoT doing some calculations, and once the program calculates the desired figures I'm sending them to two places:

- Back to the IoT Hub
- Posted to a local url with the "request" lib

Now here's where the issue appears; after several days running up and fine the program stopped, and the logs show the following issue:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 159, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 80, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 70, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 354, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1107, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1152, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1103, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 934, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 877, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line         181, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line     168, in _new_conn
self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection         object at 0x6c05f6f0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111]     Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
timeout=timeout
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
_stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 398, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='192.168.32.61', port=1880): Max retries exceeded with url: /camara (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x6c05f6f0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/main.py", line 187, in <module>
    main()
  File "/app/main.py", line 161, in main
cameraCaptureSolver.start()
  File "/app/CameraCaptureSolver.py", line 161, in start
    requests.post('http://192.168.32.61:1880/camara', data = 'camaraName':camara})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 116, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 60, in request
return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 516, in send
raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='192.168.32.61', port=1880): Max retries exceeded with url: /camara (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x6c05f6f0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))
```

Therefore the issue is with the request, but didn't know there was a limit in the number of retries.

Any ideas on how to delete or increase that number?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a complete answer, even just a suggestion to do the question orientation.

As you said "a limit in the number of retries", this is an automatic retry mechanism 
 of `urllib3` which number of retries is 3 by default, as the offical document said below.

> **[Retrying requests](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#retrying-requests)**
>
> urllib3 can automatically retry idempotent requests. This same mechanism also handles redirects. You can control the retries using the retries parameter to request(). By default, urllib3 will retry requests 3 times and follow up to 3 redirects.

You can set the number of retries with a custom count or disable it, as the code below.

> ```
> http.request('GET', 'http://httpbin.org/ip', retries=10) // set 10 for reties
> http.request('GET', 'http://nxdomain.example.com', retries=False) // disable retrying
> ```

For the error `ConnectionRefusedError`, per my experience, there are many possible reason, such as:

1. Running on a unstable network, or working behind a proxy which is not stable.
2. Some IoTHub limits or expired access token cause the connection refused issue. For this case, you need to check the status code and the related error information to find out the reason via print `r.status` and `r.data` for `r = http.request(...)`.

You can refer to the section [`IoT Hub limits`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#iot-hub-limits) of `Azure subscription and service limits, quotas, and constraints` to compare your details with these limits, and there are the error codes of [IoT Hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/common-error-codes) and [IoT Edge agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/iot-edge-runtime#iot-edge-agent) below and [`Reference - IoT Hub quotas and throttling`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-quotas-throttling) which will help you to find out the real reason.

Fig 1. The common errors of IoT Hub
[image]

Fig 2. The possible responses of IoT Edge agent sent to IoT Hub
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading your AWS subscription should increase the number of requests you can send.

Comment: But the request is sent to a local host(node-red in this case, installed in the same unit). Does this have anything to do with the (azure) subscription?

Comment: well you're sending to the iot hub at the same time you're sending to your local host right? Try to find what refuses the connection in `ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused`, also look at your aws dashboard to see if you got any notification of reaching a limit or something

Comment: The limit is at 400k daily messages and I'm barely around 30k or so, so that might be unlikely. I've tried running the same code with and without the request post line and the result is the first one failing after 30s and the second one working the entire time.